# Why am I getting XHR error 404 Not Found: loading main.ts when deploying to host?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, visual-studio, azure, typescript

Doing a small Angular 2 + TypeScript webiste which runs perfectly on my dev machine(localhost) but when I deploy to a test host (Azure Websites) I get *main.ts* not found. I search several blogs where the error goes from misspelling to using a very old version on js files, non of those solution worked for me. I'm using Visual Studio 2015 as my IDE.

This is my setup

```
PersonalBlogAngular
|
|
---app
|   |
|   app.module.ts
|   main.ts
|   [I have several components]
|
---index.html
---package.json
---tsconfig.js
```

This is my tsconfig.js

```
{
"compilerOptions": {   "target": "es6",
"module": "system",
"moduleResolution": "node",
"sourceMap": true,
"emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
"experimentalDecorators": true,
"lib": [ "es2016", "dom" ],
"noImplicitAny": true,
"suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true  
}, 
 "exclude": [
      "node_modules",
      "wwwroot/lib"
  ]
}
```

This is my package.js

```
{
"version": "1.0.0",
"name": "asp.net",
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "~2.4.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~2.4.0",
    "@angular/core": "~2.4.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~2.4.0",
    "@angular/http": "~2.4.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~2.4.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~2.4.0",
    "@angular/router": "~3.4.0",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "rxjs": "~5.0.2",
    "zone.js": "^0.7.4",
    "systemjs": "^0.19.41"
},
"devDependencies": {
}
}
```

This is my main.ts

```
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { AppModule } from './app.module';
platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```

This is my index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
<link href="assets/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="assets/css/custom.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="assets/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Indie+Flower" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://gorillacode.net/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/favicon.ico">
<!-- Polyfills for older browsers -->
<script src="https://unpkg.com/core-js/client/shim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/zone.js@0.7.4?main=browser"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/reflect-metadata@0.1.8"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/systemjs@0.19.41/dist/system.src.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/angular/angular.io/b3c65a9/public/docs/_examples/_boilerplate/systemjs.config.web.js"></script>
<script>
System.config({
        packages: {        
          app: {
            format: 'register',
            defaultExtension: 'js'
          }
        }
      });
  System.import('app').catch(function(err){ console.error(err); });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<appBlog>Loading...</appBlog>
</body>
</html>
```

With that setup I get this error  [XHR NOT FOUND main.ts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jtykB.png)

Why am I getting XHR error 404 Not Found: loading main.ts when deploying to host?

Comment: right click on main.ts in visual studio and check if that file is being copied while deploying

Comment: @TechSavvy that doesn't work. Thank you.

Comment: can you share your systemjs.config

Comment: @TechSavvy hey I just added update the code I set system config into the html. please check the code above. Thanks

Comment: Looks like system.config is being pulled from here https://cdn.rawgit.com/angular/angular.io/b3c65a9/public/docs/_examples/_boilerplate/systemjs.config.web.js , please check the path for your main.ts in packages -> app -> main